# Python3 pandas groupby apply store return value in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, return

With this dataframe :

```
   index  order_id  id_product  qty  comments                 date last_name
0      0        55   100000158    2       NaN  2020-10-26T14:33:00     Stone
1      1        55   100000339    1       NaN  2020-10-26T14:33:00     Stone
```

I create a list, groupby and apply :

```
list_test = []

df_g = df.groupby('order_id')

df_g.apply(process_order,dealer_id,file)
```

A test function to test how to return an element :

```
def process_order(df,dealer_id,file):
    if True:
        return 'bob'
```

How can I append the returned string 'test' from process_order to the list **list_test** ?

So to have as result :

```
print(list_test)
['bob']
```

Comment: I'll admit I don't understand what you're trying to do here. I belive functions passed to `apply` take only one argument.

 Having said that, the only way to append an item to the list `test_list` is to get a reference to it from outside of the function's scope (e.g. if it's declared in the module for example, or in a function in which `test_function` is nested) or pass it as an argument to the function.

Comment: I am trying to list errors while in the process_order() function so to handle them later. If everything goes well in the process_order() func, then the list_test should be empty. But if an error is catch, I would like to append it to the list

Comment: You could add the errors list to the parameters of your function, and append any errors like that. `def process_order(df,dealer_id,file, errors_list):`

Comment: Like I said there are two ways to get a reference to that list: pass it as an argument or access it from a containing scope. You could even import it for a different module if it was declared at module-level (though I wouldn;t recoomedn this.)

Answer (score 0):

Note that I agree with the other person responding that it's difficult to understand how/why you are grouping the way you are, but you may want to just create a new column called 'test' during the operation.
Something like:

```
df_g['test'] = df_g.apply(process_order,dealer_id,file)
```

After the function is applied to the group or entire dataframe you can get a list using

```
list_test = df_g['test'].tolist()
```

depending on what is in or not in, you may have to filter the dataframe or group for rows where test is empty before creating the list